# when i click on heart product show on wishlist screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, ios10

I am working on a e-commerce app. I want to do a task that when i click on heart at product. It shows in wishlist view. As you know like in e-commerce apps. Can anyone tell me how to do?

Comment: Question looks more subjective. Can you explain it where is your wishlist and product. is both are in same VC ?.  Any backend DB / service you are using at app level?.

Comment: product screen and wishlist screen are both different VC. Have u use flipkart or snapdeal app. Its like that

Comment: Ok. Then use delegate to communicate b/w both VC. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/2757496 for more info.